# Bind gridview on user control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a 2 usercontrol on a aspx page. 1 control is having search creteria and search button and 2nd usercontrol is having gridview.

How do I bind gridview when user enter creteria and click on search button.

Answer (score 1):

The click event need to be bubbled up to the aspx page and then passed to the gridview usercontrol.  See the following link how to bubble events.

http://odetocode.com/code/94.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Considering the 1st UserControl produces a DataTable. Specify a Property in 2nd UserControl which accepts the datatable and bind it to the grid inside the control.

Control2:

```
public datatable Result{get;set;}

Private void SetGrid()
{
datagrid1.datasource=Result;
datagrid1.databind();
}
```

Control1:

```
Datatable dt=SearchResult();
Control2.Result=dt;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the second user control in .ascx page you can Reference first user control
like as

```
<%@ Reference Control="first user control names comes here" %>
```

In second user control page load event you can find object of first user control using below mentioed ways:

```
UserControls_UCFirst uc1 = (UserControls_UCFirst)this.Parent.FindControl("UCFirst1");
```

then you can find search criteria objects (TextBox, DropDownList, etc..) of first user control.

```
TextBox txt = (TextBox)(uc1.FindControl("txtName"));
```

Through above process you can bind grid view.

Hope it will helps.

Answer (score 0):

First Get the searched Results in a DataTable, and Stored the DataTable in a ViewState. And then set the DataTable in a ViewState as datasource of the GridView.
Like this,

```
 GridView1.DataSource = ViewState["DataTable1"];
 GridView1.DataBind();
```

I hope this will help u.